# How to public string return edit text?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to change the return value in the public class.

I want to make MD5 encrypted.
How can I do it.
I searched on msdn.microsoft.com, but I did not. :(

```
        public string Password {
        get { return SystemProccess.MD5Encrypt(Password); }
    }
```

Comment: `I  searched on msdn`, What did you search? How to write a property? How to use `System.Security.Cryptography.MD5`? See the first result of google for `c# MD5` :)

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have a circular reference. You may want to use a second property, one to set the password with plain text, and another to get the encrypted one.

```
public string Password { get; set; }

public string EncryptedPassword {
    get { return GetMd5Hash(Password); }
}
```

I found the following code method for generating hashes from MSDN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5(v=vs.110).aspx. Be sure you include the proper namespaces.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
```

And then add the following to your class.

```
static string GetMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string input)
{

    // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
    byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

    // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
    // and create a string.
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
    // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    // Return the hexadecimal string.
    return sBuilder.ToString();
}
```

If for security in case you did not want to store the original password, you could use a setter. Notice that the property uses a private field to store and access the encrypted value, so the original non-encrypted password is not stored.

```
private string _EncryptedPassword = null;
public string EncryptedPassword 
{
    get { return _EncryptedPassword ; }
    set { _EncryptedPassword = GetMd5Hash(value); }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: `Convert.ToBase64String(data)` ?   `BitConverter.ToString(data)` ? Don't you think they are simpler?

Comment: You are right. OP mentioned MSDN so I wanted to include that as a tutorial but I must have stumbled upon one that is a little dated.

Comment: He also mentioned MD5 encryption. Is that the same as Base64? I am not well versed in cryptography.

Comment: Base64 encoding is just another way to convert an arbitraty byte array to printable text. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: @L.B I am quite sure L.B. is talking about the convertion you made in the cycle, and if this is what he means he's right that's fater. He is not talking about MD5. But at least you know how to search MSDN +1 lol